# map JSON response having no root element to POJO JAXB binding?

Tags: json, xml-parsing, jaxb, apache-camel, pojo

how do you map JSON ( no root elem ) to XML using JAXB annotations? 
seems a common thing? has anyone experienced this too? I've searched.... thanks in advance!!!!

Karaf version               2.4.0.redhat-630310
Camel                       2.17.0.redhat-630310

Trying to first authenticate, obtain the access_token and then use the access_token to gain access to the systems resources having authorization to use.  how do you map JSON ( no root elem ) to XML using JAXB annotations?

here is the JSON response:

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOrZXkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.","token_type": "bearer","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciXkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.", "expires_in": 86399, "scope": "password.write openid","jti":75dcd85bd1247b4968f8802e54a9cc1"}
```

my POJO model class

```
package com.ge.dig.predix.entities;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entities {

@XmlElement(name="access_token")
private String access_token;
@XmlElement(name="token_type")
private String token_type;
@XmlElement(name="refresh_token")
private String refresh_token;
@XmlElement(name="expires_in")
private String expires_in;
@XmlElement(name="scope")
private String scope;
@XmlElement(name="jti")
private String jti;

public String getAccessToken() {
    return access_token;
}
public void setAccessToken(String access_token) {
    this.access_token = access_token;
}
public String getTokenType() {
    return token_type;
}
public void setTokenType(String token_type) {
    this.token_type = token_type;
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am only concerned with JSON, I will use Jackson Annotations. however, I would still like to understand how this would work using XML parsing. If anyone knows, please advice. thank you!

so, this is my JSON mapping entity class supporting JSON.

```
package com.myapp.entities;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "token_type", "scope", "jti" })
public class TokenEntities {

private String access_token;
private String token_type;
private String refresh_token;
private String expires_in;
private String scope;
private String jti;

@JsonCreator
public TokenEntities(@JsonProperty("access_token") String access_token,
                     //@JsonProperty("token_type")String token_type,
                     @JsonProperty("refresh_token")String refresh_token,
                     @JsonProperty("expires_in")int expires_in,
                     //@JsonProperty("scope")String scope,
                     //@JsonProperty("jti")String jti) {
    this.access_token = access_token;
    //this.token_type = token_type;
    this.refresh_token = refresh_token;
    this.expires_in = expires_in;
    //this.scope = scope;
    //this.jti = jti;
}

public String getAccessToken() {
    return access_token;
}

public String getTokenType() {
    return token_type;
}

public String getRefreshToken() {
    return refresh_token;
}

public int getExpires_in() {
    return expires_in;
}

public String getScope() {
    return scope;
}

public String getJti() {
    return jti;
}
}
```